# What could be the cause of Forbidden command : SHOW WARNINGS to MySql from SpringJDBC

Tags: java, mysql, spring-jdbc, paas

Recently, I created a java app on an appengine Paas (name [jd-app.com](http://jd-app.com)).  But a very general SpringJDBC application wouldn't run because it shows exception for a simple query like "select * from user" for MySql.  The files are from [http://www.beingjavaguys.com](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/07/spring-jdbc-template-with-spring-mvc.html)

Very frustrated after a few days of trying so I am putting some code and configuration here hoping someone with knowledge or similar experience can help.

### Code:

UserDaoImpl.java

```
public List<User> getUserList() {
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
    String sql = "select * from user";
    userList = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new UserRowMapper());
```

### spring-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://10.0.16.16:4066/databasenamehidden" />
    <property name="username" value="xxxxx" />
    <property name="password" value="yyyyyy" />
</bean>
```

### Exception:

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select * from wp_users]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [3013]; **Forbidden command : SHOW WARNINGS**; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Forbidden command : SHOW WARNINGS

Root cause

...
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:413)
    org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:437)
    com.beingjavaguys.dao.UserDaoImpl.getUserList(**UserDaoImpl.java:63**)

### Discussion

On the same Paas, I uploaded a Wordpress app which can access MySql and runs perfectly.  But if I config that database in the spring-servlet.xml and select * from wp_users, then I will also see this exception from the SpringJDBC app.

I tried to change that sql query to other statement and I always get same exceptions.  So what could be a reason for that?  I can upload more code upon request.

Comment: Try to turn off the warnings on your DB `SET GLOBAL LOG_WARNINGS = 0` or suppress warnings using mysql command line `nowarning`

Comment: Nikhil, is there a way to disable warning from java side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Nikhil, the error is from a forbidden command, and that is SHOW WARNINGS.

Maybe your Paas doesn't allow SHOW WARNINGS?